# Query cardinality of a dimension without multiple calls?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the Google Analytics API and I'd like to get the cardinality of my page data.

It would be possible, of course, to just pull page + page views, chucked, and count, but I wanted to see if perhaps I've overlooked a portion of the API that offers some sort of meta analysis of the dataset to prevent me having to loop through the raw data?

Comment: Please edit your question show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your solution.

Comment: Thanks, @DaImTo, but that's irrelevant here. What do you want to see, my Google search history? I'm asking about what an API offers, now how to use it.

Comment: You are using the Google analytics api i would like to see the code you are using to request the data.  Explain exactly what data you want to see.

Comment: This isn't about the API library I'm using and what my code looks like. I'm asking about what the API offers, so there is no code to show because I don't know that the API offers what I would be trying to get with code I haven't written. If there's a better Stack Exchange for that kind of question, please point me to it.